# How to Serializing a class containing same class using XML Serialization

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

My class currently looks like this

```
[Serializable()]
public class TreeViewItem
{
  private string _sTexte;
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("Texte")]
  public string Texte 
  {
    get { return _sTexte; }
    set { Label = _sTexte = value; } 
  }

  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("Parent")]
  public TreeViewItem Parent { get; set; }
}
```

I got an error when I serialize this class with `Parent` property.

However, I can serialize with success if I ignore the `Parent` property as follows:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]
public TreeViewItem Parent { get; set; }
```

How can I serialize this class to a file including the `Parent` property?

Comment: It'd help if you posted a sample of your XML files so we don't have to guess its structure.

Comment: I don't think that the OP has any sample XML files, as the problem is that the class is failing to serialize.

Comment: What is the exact error? (including the `.InnerException`s); what happens? Is there maybe a `Children` property you aren't showing? I would expect an error if you have a cyclic graph, but your model doesn't show that (unless a `TreeViewItem` has *itself* as its own `Parent`). BTW, you don't need `[Serializable]` when using `XmlSerializer`.

Comment: Looks like you might be having a recursive relation in this object graph. You cannot serialize recursive relations in XML.

Comment: OK Darin. I must find another method to reference "Parent" to avoid recursive relation. Maybe an ID .....

Comment: By recursive I meant that you have a TreeViewItem instance whose Parent property is pointing to another TreeViewItem instance whose Parent property is pointing to the first TreeViewItem instance. And the circle is closed. And the XML serializer is going wild. So what you have to do is not find another method to reference Parent but to fix the method that is populating this object graph - the method that is giving you an instance of this `TreeViewItem` class.